# How to pipe file read stream to compute sha256 hash and write to write stream at same time in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, stream, cryptography

How do you both compute the sha256 hash of a read stream in Node.js, *and* write to a write stream for it? I am going to use this to name a file after its sha256 hash, first giving the file a temporary name, then after the file is fully written, rename it to the sha256 hash name.

I tried this, but it writes the sha256 hash to the output file instead of the contents of the input file, and `hash.read()` returns null.

```
import fs from 'fs'
import crypto from 'crypto'

const read = fs.createReadStream('tmp/input.txt')
const write = fs.createWriteStream('tmp/output.txt')
const hash = crypto.createHash('sha256')
hash.setEncoding('hex')

read.on('end', () => {
  hash.end()
  console.log(hash.read()) // the desired sha256 sum
})

// read all file and pipe it (write it) to the hash object
read.pipe(hash).pipe(write)
```

How do I do both at the same time?

Comment: Does `read.pipe(hash); read.pipe(write);` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NodeJS supports piping data to multiple destinations. However, one must ensure no calls to `await` between setting up the different consuming pipelines. If there are async interrupts, the first stream consumer might race to consume bytes from the read stream before the other streams are ready.

What the snippet below does:

- Reading and Hashing: A readable stream from 'input.txt' is pipelined into a hash object (from `crypto`) to calculate the SHA-256 hash in hexadecimal format. This hash is stored to a variable.
- Writing File: Simultaneously, the same readable stream is pipelined into a writable stream targeted at 'destination.txt', effectively copying the file.
- Waiting for Completion: `Promise.all` is used with `stream.promises.pipeline` to wait for both the hashing and writing operations to complete.
- Renaming File: Finally, `fs.promises.rename` changes the name of 'destination.txt' to `${hash}.txt`, where `${hash}` is the calculated hash value.

```js
import crypto from 'crypto'
import fs from 'fs'
import stream from 'stream';

const input = fs.createReadStream('input.txt');

let hash;
const hashPromise = stream.promises.pipeline(
  input,
  crypto.createHash('sha256').setEncoding('hex'),
  async function (source) {
    hash = (await source.toArray())[0];
  }
);

const writePromise = stream.promises.pipeline(
  input,
  fs.createWriteStream('destination.txt')
);

// Now that the pipeline is set up, start the flow of data..
await Promise.all([
  // Await the hash operations to complete.
  hashPromise,
  // Await the write operation to complete.
  writePromise
]);

// Finally, rename the destination file to the hash value.
await fs.promises.rename('destination.txt', `${hash}.txt`);
```